Coloring the content of a textarea tag as JSON (with colors)

I have an Angular application , in this app , i have a text area that i will always write json text to it , what i want is at the same moment that i am writing in this textarea , in case the json is valid, i want the text to be colorfull ( Key with a color and value with another color)(this is something similair to Postman when writing JSON ) .
What i have tried so far :
HTML:
` <textarea
     pInputText
     placeholder="required name and schemaJson object"
     formControlName="schema"
     id="schema" rows="10" cols="50" required
     (input)="updateTextColor($event.target.value)">
                        </textarea>````





TypeScript:
updateTextColor(text: string): void {
    try {
      const jsonObject = JSON.parse(text);
      const coloredText = this.colorizeJSON(jsonObject);
      document.getElementById('schema').innerHTML = coloredText;
    } catch (error) {
      // If JSON parsing fails, keep the text as is
      document.getElementById('schema').innerText = text;
    }
  }

  colorizeJSON(obj: any): string {
    let coloredText = '';
    for (const key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        coloredText += `<span class="json-key">${key}</span>: `;
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
          coloredText += this.colorizeJSON(obj[key]);
        } else {
          coloredText += `<span class="json-value">${obj[key]}</span>`;
        }
        coloredText += ', ';
      }
    }
    // Remove trailing comma and return
    return coloredText.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
  }

PS:i have tried using Ngx-monaco, but failed due to other errors`

Textarea element does not support rendering HTML content directly within it. Here is similar question. In case of angular you don't need to create string with html string as a content in your .ts file. Use *ngFor/ @for and *ngIf/@if to create html structure you need (using divs and spans) and then iterate over key/value you got from that JSON and assign them to the spans using binding like this:
<div class="some-class-to-look-like-textarea-before">
    <span *ngFor="let spanColor of parsedColors" [style.color]="spanColor">Your text here</span>
</div>

